Product of topologies and comparison
In a certain exercise, I am asked to compare, if possible, the topologies in $X \times X$ $\tau_1, \tau_2$, where $\tau_1$ is the product topology of discrete and cofinite over an ordered set $X$, $\tau_1 "=" \tau_{d} \times \tau_{\text{cof}}$ and $\tau_2$ is the one induced by the lexicographic order. I reached the conclusion that $\tau_1$ is coarser than $\tau_2$. I also find it important to say that $\tau_2$ is the product of discrete and usual one (the one induced by the order relationship), $\tau_2 "=" \tau_d \times \tau_{\text{usual}}$ (I quoted both equal signs because I know is not exactly the same).

My reasoning is, basically, that since the bases of the first factor of the cartesian product are the same in each of both topologies (both are the product of the discrete by another one), and since $\tau_{\text{cof}}$ is coarser than $\tau_{\text{usual}}$, then that is the proof. Is it right?
